# asked about deviceid from clGetDeviceInfo and catalyst control center

Tags: opencl, device

any one help me,

i am new in opencl

i want to know about device-id in command clGetDeviceInfo

the value of device-id must be the same value that show in tool catalyst control center

that show in image http://uploads.im/6rChS.jpg

the device-id return from this function clGetDeviceInfo  must equal to 6740

thanks all

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `cl_device_id` parameter to `clGetDeviceInfo` should be one you got from `clGetDeviceIDs` (which, in turn uses a `cl_platform_id` you received from `clGetPlatformIDs`). The device ID might match the one you see in Catalyst Control Center but that doesn't matter for anything; you can't (or at least shouldn't) access the device with a hard-coded ID and should only use IDs returned from the runtime.